# How can a Nordic cross be projected onto a sphere without stretching?

Tags: uv

[image]

Hey, does anybody know how to make it so that the lines on the flag going up don't get smaller?

Comment: I hate being a nitpick, but that's the Norwegian flag, and the cross on it is a Nordic cross. Norway is indeed part of Scandinavia, but the Nordic cross is also used on the flags of Sweden, which is part of Scandinavia, Denmark, which culturally is considered a Scandinavian country, but strictly speaking, not geographically so, Finland and Iceland, neither of which are Scandinavian countries, but have a lot of common grounds culturally. There is no single Scandinavian flag.

Comment: You good you good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>U</kbd> -> **Project from view** or default texture coordinates should work:

[image]